# How to "ellipsize" the title of a AlertDialog in the middle?

Tags: java, android, string, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` whose **title** is supposed to be something like

> Copying "xxx" to...

In case `xxx` is a very long string I would like it to be shortened instead of the whole title: it's important that the "*to...*" part is *visible*!

To make an example, if `xxx == "A very long text here is being displayed!"` I want the title of the AlertDialog to be:

> Copying "A very long text here is bein..." to...

How to do it?

Comment: Do you need that quote as well ? eg : "xxxxxxxxxxbein.." to.......

Comment: @Charuka yes, I need it exactly as it looks in the text I wrote!

Comment: basic java nothing else let me quickly do something

Comment: did you understand what i did?

Comment: Yes! Check my comment under your answer please

Answer (score 2):

**Logic** = take a string> decide length you need to display  >  check the  length of the string you have> remove unwanted characters to keep the length you want  > reset new sting with other characters you need to add > set it as head!

```
 String headText = "add anything you want here as head";


        String newHead;
        int maxCharYouWant= 25; // your word limit to display

        if(headText.length()>25){
            newHead = headText.substring(0, Math.min(headText.length(), 18)); // Get the first N number of words-> here 18
            newHead = "\""+newHead+".."+"\""+"to.."; // reset with your format 
        }else {
            newHead =  headText; // length is ok no need to change it
        }


        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.body_layout, null); // for body

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Test.this);
        TextView textView = new TextView(Test.this);
        textView.setText(newHead);  
        builder.setCustomTitle(textView);// set your heading 

        builder.setView(dialogLayout);
        builder.show();
```

**Edit:** To get the number of chars for the screen you can use a some method like this (I did not tested this on multiple devises for 1080 it returns 32.. you can try and see )

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = (int)((float)size.x/metrics.scaledDensity);

        TextView textView = new TextView(Test.this);
        int totalCharstoFit= textView.getPaint().breakText(headText,  0, headText.length(), true, width, null);
```

Read more about [breakText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#breakText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20float,%20float%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Thanks @Charuka . My problem is also that **I don't know in advance** the space available on the screen of the smartphone.  Therefore I can't use `int maxCharYouWant = 25;`. Any suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: @Robb1 any way even if you add 1000 characters ,note i add the head by setting a  `textView` so if does not have enough space in the first line for the head it will go the the second.. third .. like wise

Comment: read this too http://stackoverflow.com/a/10464760/5188159

Comment: It's not a problem of lines. What I mean is that on a 5" screen I want it to be displayed as «Copying "A very long text here is bein..." to...» while on a 4" screen something like «Copying "A very long text..." to...». It has to adapt according to the size of the screen!

Comment: use this  `DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = (int)((float)size.x/metrics.scaledDensity);` ......
`int totalCharstoFit= textView.getPaint().breakText(headText,  0, headText.length(), true, width, null);` get the int and set it to yourcharlimit i got 32 as the limit

Comment: @Robb1 now you can try and see

Comment: thanks for the help. Where did you get `size` you use in `int width = (int)((float)size.x/metrics.scaledDensity);` ?

Comment: `Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = (int)((float)size.x/metrics.scaledDensity);`

Comment: @Robb1 did that work for you?